# function problem satisfy some conditions

Tags: functions

There exists a function $f(x)$ satisfying $f(0)=1,f'(0)=-1,f(x)>0\forall x \in R$. then which one is right.

$(a)\; f''(x)<0$ for all x

$(b)\; -1<f''(x)<0$ for all $x$

$(c)\; -2 \leq f''(x)\leq -1$ for all $x$

$(d)\; f''(x)<-2$ for all $x$

Try: for $f(x)>0$ means function $f(x)$ is above $x$ axis

$(a)\; f''(x)<0$ for all $x$ means function concave downward .(not true)

$(b)\; -1 <f''(x)<0$ (not true)

same way for $c$ and $d$ , someone please explain me

Comment: What if $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x}$?

Comment: I think none of options are correct, as you say

Comment: @Alex did you try computing $f''(x)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Yup. Seems like there's a typo somewhere.